# Convert int to it's ascii counterpart in xquery

Tags: casting, xquery

I want to convert say 65 to 'A' in xquery, how do you do that?
There's a XML in which I've to insert sequencing into, like this.

```
<a>
<b>A
</b>
<b>B
</b>
<b>C
</b>
</a>
```

Comment: If I understand the requirement correctly, you may be able to do this without calling `codepoints-to-string()`. Consider, for example, using `format-integer(posiition(), 'A')`.

Comment: Yes, it can be done this way also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`codepoints-to-string(65)` gives `A`: https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/b4GWVi, see the spec https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-codepoints-to-string.